# FIND folders and MV (rename) them using FIND, GREP, XARGS, and AWK?

Tags: bash, awk, grep, find

I'm trying to move my LOG folders.  Here is what I have so far.

```
cd archive
find .. -type d -name 'LOGS' | xargs -I '{}' mv {} `echo {} | awk -F/ 'NF > 1 { print $(NF - 1)"-LOGS"; }'`
```

Unfortunately -->  `echo {} | awk -F/ 'NF > 1 { print $(NF - 1)"-LOGS"; }'`  <-- evaluates immediately.  So doesn't give me the file name that I would prefer.

```
mv ../app1/LOGS app1-LOGS
mv ../app2/LOGS app2-LOGS
```

Is there a way to do this in a single line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using xargs:

```
find .. -type d -name 'LOGS' |
xargs -I {} bash -c 'd="${1%/*}"; mv "$1" "${d##*/}-LOGS"' - {}
```

Or else you can do that like this using process substitution:

```
cd archive

while IFS= read -rd '' dir; do
   d="${dir%/*}"
   d="${d##*/}"
   mv "$dir" "$d-LOGS"
done < <(find .. -type d -name 'LOGS' -print0)
```